# Is it possible to output a file? (note, not "to" a file)

Tags: c++, image, file-io, pipe

I'm thinking to write a script that uses one program to make image files, and another program to analyse these files.

The simplest way would be to use piping, but these are image files, not text files, so instead of outputting text I was wondering is it possible to have an image file as the output of a program?

If not, I suppose I could write image files to the directory, process them, then delete them, but I'd still like to know the possibility of a program's output.

**EDIT:** Sorry I should have mentioned, I am free to change/add to the first program (that makes the images) but the second program is not my code, and takes a .jpg as input.

Comment: You don't say which OS you're writing for but you can generally pipe 8-bit data ok, so I don't see why piping wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with piping binary data across a pipe! You probably need to add a bit of control protocol if you want to pipe multiple files, e.g., to indicate what are the different files. For example, you might want to send the size followed by the bytes making up an image.

Answer (score 2):

Piping is not specific to text files. You just output the binary data of the image and have the second program take the binary data as input. All files are essentially just a bunch of bits and piping just redirects where those bits go.